# iPhone and Windows Active Directory

Tags: iphone, active-directory

Is it posable to make an app that can connect to a Windows Active Directory Server and do something like create a new user account or disable an existing account or retrieve a status flag...? help me please...!

What i actually want is that, my windows server has all the web services and database which is capable to run a web application. now i am about to design an iphone version of the same web app. the users information are stored in an Active Directory. is there exist a direct connection between the iphone and the AD??? do i need to write any other web service particular for the iphone version??? what all things i need to setup for that.???

Thanks,

Shibin

Comment: Good question.  Would like to see answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can set up a web service on AD server to handle AD related operations.

like this way:
[native AD operate code]<---->[web service]<------> iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Our Smash! User Manager app does this and is available for both IOS and Android for FREE.

APPLE:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smash-user-manager/id407785473?mt=8

ANDROID:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.weston.android.usermanagerforwindows

Answer (score 1):

ADAssist at http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/active-directory-assist/id528953910?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might look into porting [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to a legitimate iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly ways to do this.  There are a few applications on the App Store that do this now.  (Several mentioned here, although my favorite "[AD HelpDesk](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-helpdesk/id366597535?mt=8)" hasn't gotten a plug yet).

Probably the easiest way to go about it would be to use [ADWS](http://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/the-active-directory-web-service-adws/) to allow web service access to the DC.  This of course requires a 2008 R2 DC.

If you don't do that you will have to use native protocols such as LDAP to communicate with the DC.  You can incorporate [openLDAP](http://www.openldap.org) source code into your iPhone app, and do LDAP queries against the DC directly.